# Transclude Component and still use ngFor

Tags: angular, transclusion

I'm attempting to emulate pagination on an array of data returned from an API. 
This is working for me perfectly for me, however what I need to do is nest another component which is using ngFor inside this, with it's ngFor data being passed down from my transcluded component.

If I run a debugger inside my transclusion component I can see my full array coming in, I can also see it being spliced and a new object created containing the data I have mutated.

However, when I attempt to render my component using the ngFor and pass in the new array, nothing is rendered.

I have added a debugger to this component also and it does not appear to be triggered at all as the debugger does not even fire.

My code is as follows :

**object-transclusion.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-object-transclusion',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class ObjectTransclusionComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() items: any;

    public pageNo: number = 1;
    public paginatedItems: string[];

    private results_per_page: number = 1;
    private totalPages: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.totalPages = this.getMaxPages();
        this.updatePaginationState();
    }

    public nextPage(): void {
        if (this.pageNo < this.totalPages) {
            this.pageNo++;
            this.updatePaginationState();
        }
    }

    public prevPage(): void {
        if (this.pageNo > 1) {
            this.pageNo--;
            this.updatePaginationState();
        }
    }

    private updatePaginationState(): void {
        this.paginatedItems = [
            ...this.items.slice(
                (this.pageNo - 1) * this.results_per_page, this.pageNo * this.results_per_page
            )
        ];
    }

    private getMaxPages(): number {
        return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.results_per_page);
    }
}
```

**event-table.component.pug**

```
.event-table-container
    life-event-table-header
    app-object-transclusion([items]='events')
        life-event-table-row(*ngFor='let event of paginatedItems', [event]='event', [canModifyLifeEvents]='canModifyLifeEvents')
```

How can I sort data in the transclusion component, making it availble for a component rendered via ng-content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like the solution is to add a local template variable to

```
app-object-transclusion(#transclude [items]='events')
```

This allows me to output the data using

```
*ngFor='let event of transclude.paginatedItems'
```

Not as elegant as I like, but it is working.